# DSolve running for 4.5 hours

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
    (*Define the Young's modulus as a function of volume fraction*)
youngsModulus[vf_, E1_, E2_] := E1 + (E2 - E1)*vf

(*Hypothetical material properties*)
E1 = 70*10^9; (*70 GPa*)
E2 = 210*10^9; (*210 GPa*)

(*Beam dimensions and load*)
L = 2; (*Length in meters*)
b = 0.1; (*Width in meters*)
h = 0.05; (*Thickness in meters*)
q = 1000; (*Uniform load in N/m*)

(*Number of elements and nodes in the z-direction*)
numElements = 16;
numNodes = numElements + 1;

(*Function to calculate deflection for a given volume fraction \
distribution*)
calculateDeflection[vfList_] := 
 Module[{EList, I, w, x, differentialEquation, boundaryConditions, 
   solution},(*Convert volume fraction list to Young's modulus list*)
  EList = youngsModulus[#, E1, E2] & /@ vfList;
  (*Average Young's modulus for the beam*)Eavg = Mean[EList];
  (*Moment of inertia*)I = b*h^3/12;
  (*Euler-Bernoulli beam equation*)
  differentialEquation = Eavg*I*D[w[x], {x, 4}] == q;
  (*Boundary conditions for a simply supported beam*)
  boundaryConditions = {w[0] == 0, w[L] == 0, w''[0] == 0, 
    w''[L] == 0};
  (*Solve the differential equation*)
  solution = 
   DSolve[{differentialEquation, boundaryConditions}, w[x], x];
  (*Return maximum deflection*)
  MaxValue[{w[x] /. First[solution], 0 <= x <= L}, x]]

(*Define the optimization variables*)
vfList = Array[vf, numNodes];

(*Define the constraints-volume fractions between 0 and 1*)
constraints = And @@ Thread[0 <= vfList <= 1];

(*Optimization function*)
optimizeBeam := 
 Module[{result}, 
  result = 
   NMinimize[{calculateDeflection[vfList], constraints}, vfList, 
    Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
  vfList /. Last[result]]

(*Run Optimization*)
optimizedVf = optimizeBeam;

(*Output the optimized volume fractions*)
Print["Optimized Volume Fractions: ", optimizedVf]
```

Here I want to find out the optimal volume fraction value for an FGM simply supported beam. I am trying to optimize the Vf here for minimizing deflection. And the code is running forever. Please help.I do not think it should take such long time to compute. So, I want to ask you if my approach is right?

Comment: Please focus your question on a specific problem. "Fix this for me" is not specific enough.

Comment: The code runs fast enough for fewer elements, up to `numElements = 12;` But, the volume fractions are all 1.0 for any number of elements.  This result is not surprising, since the stiffest material should give least deflection.

Comment: @LouisB thanks.